# How to show that this product produces I

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Consider $f$:

$f: \boldsymbol{R^{n}} \rightarrow \boldsymbol{R^{n}} $

$f(x)=\frac{x}{\left \| x \right \|^{2}}$

I know that the derivative of $f$ is:

$\left \| x \right \|^{-2}\mathbf{I}-2\left \| x \right \|^{-4}xx^{t}$

How can i show that the derivative of $f(f(x)) = \mathbf{I}$

i.e. by the chain rule that $f'(f(x))f'(x) = \mathbf{I}$

Answer (score 1):

It is simpler if you compute the composition explicitly.

Compute $\phi(x)=f(f(x)) = x$. Then $\phi'(x) = I$.